# Quartz Scheduler not stopping after shutdown

Tags: java, jboss, quartz-scheduler

I'm using the currently latest quartz 1.8.3 on jboss 4.0.5.
The quartz jobs are persistent and saved into a local database.
When I call the shutdown or standby method on the executing quartz scheduler object
jobs still continue to execute by the scheduler, only that the jobs state is empty and the execution fails.

I would expect (at least according to quartz API documentation) that when I shutdown or make the scheduler standby, that jobs previously scheduled into the database will not be executed.

If calling shutdown or standby on the scheduler is not the method to achieve that, what is?

*The jobs are not just finishing the execution but planned jobs continue to be triggered.*

Here is additional info as asked:

```
public class QuartzNotificationsSchedulerBean implements NotificationsScheduler, ServletContextAware {
...
public String scheduleNotification(Notification notification) {

        // Schedule the job with the trigger
        try {
            // Define job instance  

                String      groupName   = this.createNotificationGroupName(notification);
                String      triggerName = this.createNoficationTriggerName(notification);
                String      jobName     = this.createNoficationJobName(notification);
                JobDetail   job         = new JobDetail(jobName, groupName , ScheduledNotificationJob.class);

                JobDataMap jobDataMap = new JobDataMap();
                jobDataMap.putAll(notification.getContext());     
                job.setJobDataMap(jobDataMap);

                Calendar notificationTime = notification.getTime();    

                Trigger trigger = new SimpleTrigger(triggerName, groupName , notificationTime.getTime());

                scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);        

                return trigger.getName();           
        } catch (SchedulerException e) {
            throw new NotificationScheduleException(e, notification);
        }

        return null;
    }

public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {      
        this.sf = (SchedulerFactory) servletContext.getAttribute(QuartzInitializerListener.QUARTZ_FACTORY_KEY);

        try {
            scheduler =  sf.getScheduler();
            if(scheduler.isStarted() == false) {
                scheduler.start();
            }

        } catch (SchedulerException e) {        
            logger.error("Failed to load Quartz scheduler ", e);        
        }
    }
}
```

The following is a copy of the quartz configuration properties:

```
#============================================================================
# Configure Main Scheduler Properties  
#============================================================================

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = scheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction = true

#============================================================================
# Configure ThreadPool  
#============================================================================

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 45
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5

#============================================================================
# Configure JobStore  
#============================================================================

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
#org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = FOR_QUARTZ
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000


#============================================================================
# Configure Datasources  
#============================================================================

org.quartz.dataSource.FOR_QUARTZ.jndiURL = java:jdbc/live-quartz
```

Here is a snippet from the web.xml where the quartz is initialized:

```
 <!--  START NOTIFICATION SERVICE -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>config-file</param-name>
        <param-value>wm_quartz.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>start-scheduler-on-load</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>    

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Thanks

Comment: What kind of quartz scheduler are you using? Could you post the initilization could of the service and the scheduler?

Comment: are just the running jobs finishing their execution or are planned jobs executing also?

Comment: can you post some of the code with configuration detail

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If there are any jobs executing when you call shutdown, whether to interrupt those jobs or not depends on the property `org.quartz.scheduler.interruptJobsOnShutdown`.

See http://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/QTZ-41?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel . I am unable to find more documentation on this.

The other property is `org.quartz.scheduler.makeSchedulerThreadDaemon=true`, which will shutdown quartz scheduler as soon as your calling thread shuts down. I do not know what happens to the state of the jobs.

As mentioned in the comments, post some code and configuration to get clear answer.

Comment: I used you answer but still get error. Please answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52810855/the-web-application-root-appears-to-have-started-a-thread-named-pollingconfig

Comment: Nearly nine years later the property still isn't documented

Answer (score 5):

Please try to apply with these configuration when init scheduler

```
org.quartz.threadPool.makeThreadsDaemons=true
org.quartz.scheduler.makeSchedulerThreadDaemon=true
org.quartz.scheduler.interruptJobsOnShutdown=true
org.quartz.plugin.shutdownhook.class = org.quartz.plugins.management.ShutdownHookPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.shutdownhook.cleanShutdown = true
```

You can refer to this link for more detail: https://www.techpaste.com/2016/03/quartz-scheduler-shutdown/

Answer (score 4):

you can use 
`org.quartz.plugin.shutdownhook.cleanShutdown=TRUE`
in your quartz properties file

Comment: I used your answer but still getting error. Please answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52810855/the-web-application-root-appears-to-have-started-a-thread-named-pollingconfig