# The web application appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot 1.5.9.RELEASE + Java 8 + Tomcat 9
+ Jersey + Oracle and my app has scheduled method defined as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class ScheduleConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100);
    }
}
```

The job class:

```
@Component
public class ClearCacheJob {



    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 3600000, initialDelay = 10000)
    public void clearErrorCodesCache() {
        try {
            logger.info("######## ClearCacheJob #########");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception in ClearCacheJob", e);
        }
    }

}
```

Also I have a class to deregister the Oracle driver as follows:

```
@WebListener
public class ContainerContextClosedHandler implements ServletContextListener {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContainerContextClosedHandler.class);

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        logger.info("######### contextInitialized #########");
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
        logger.info("######### contextDestroyed #########");
        Enumeration<Driver> drivers = DriverManager.getDrivers();
        while (drivers.hasMoreElements()) {
            Driver driver = drivers.nextElement();
            try {
                DriverManager.deregisterDriver(driver);
                logger.info(String.format("deregistering jdbc driver: %s", driver));
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.info(String.format("Error deregistering driver %s", driver), e);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

but when stopping Tomcat I am getting the following error:

```
WARNING [Thread-11] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.clearReferencesThreads The web application [hai] 
appears to have started a thread named [Timer-0] but has failed to stop it. 
 This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
 java.lang.Object.wait(Unknown Source)
 java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Unknown Source)
 java.util.TimerThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Comment: Not sure... Have you tried this?
org.quartz.scheduler.interruptJobsOnShutdown=true

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/3475101/2158271

Comment: i am not using quartz

Comment: Do you use shiro or c3p0 in your project?

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh  try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6603051/how-can-i-shutdown-spring-task-executor-scheduler-pools-before-all-other-beans-i

Comment: The problem is that you do not know who started the TimerThread.  I would recommend that you create a java agent that adds a print statement that produces a stack trace to the TimerThread ctor.  You could then use that information to determine who started the TimerThread.

Comment: @Claudio Corsi, any link for example on how to do that ?

Comment: Did you try to extend your `ContainerContextClosedHandler.contextDestroyed` to manually shutdown the `taskExecutor` and/or the scheduler respectively. Similar to the fix suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2730354/spring-scheduler-shutdown-error)

Comment: You can debug it using Eclipse by placing a breakpoint in the TimerThread constructor, after having the source code for your JDK version attached.

Comment: @diogenesgg Gone are the days of having to attach the source to debug into 3rd party code. If you're using the best IDE money can buy that is (not sure if community edition has decompiler by default).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change your `ScheduleConfig` to use `shutdownNow` instead of `shutdown` as destroy method.

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class ScheduleConfig implements SchedulingConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureTasks(ScheduledTaskRegistrar taskRegistrar) {
        taskRegistrar.setScheduler(taskExecutor());
    }

    @Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdownNow")
    public Executor taskExecutor() {
        return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

I want to share some solutions with root cause analysis of this issue.

---

> ## For Oracle Users

### Solution #1

You should remove your Oracle driver from Tomcat's `/lib` folder.
I was facing the same issue and it got resolved.

**Note:** Let the Oracle driver be in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder.

### Solution #2

You can use real hack by sleeping thread.

```
@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent servletContextEvent) {
    logger.info("######### contextDestroyed #########");
    Enumeration<Driver> drivers = DriverManager.getDrivers();
    while (drivers.hasMoreElements()) {
        Driver driver = drivers.nextElement();
        try {
            DriverManager.deregisterDriver(driver);
            logger.info(String.format("deregistering jdbc driver: %s", driver));
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            logger.info(String.format("Error deregistering driver %s", driver), e);
        }
    }
    try { Thread.sleep(2000L); } catch (Exception e) {} // Use this thread sleep
}
```

**Resource Link:** [Solution to “Tomcat can’t stop [Abandoned connection cleanup thread]”](https://www.ralph-schuster.eu/2014/07/09/solution-to-tomcat-cant-stop-an-abandoned-connection-cleanup-thread/)

### Solution #3

[Svetlin Zarev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2588800/svetlin-zarev) has told nothing to worry about. It is the standard message of tomcat. He has given root cause analysis like below:

> This problem is occurred when an application has started
> ScheduledExecutor (but this will happen with any other
> Thread/TheadPool) and didn't shut it down on contextDestroyed. So
> check if you are shutting down your threads on application/server
> stop.

**Resource Link:** [Tomcat8 memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28106807/2293534)

### Solution #4

**For Oracle users**, there are multiple answers in this post: [To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3320400/to-prevent-a-memory-leak-the-jdbc-driver-has-been-forcibly-unregistered)

---

> ## For MySQL users

### Solution #5

**Root Cause Analysis with Solution:**

> The cleanup thread for abandoned connections in the
> **NonRegisteringDriver** class was refactored to have a static shutdown method. Memory was allocated but never released. If you
> encountered this leak problem, implement the context listener in your
> application with the `AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.shutdown()`
> call in the `contextDestroyed` method.
>
> This issue was found in applications running under the Tomcat
> application server, but it might have also applied to other
> application servers.
>
> ### For example:
>
> ```
> @WebListener
> public class YourThreadsListener implements ServletContextListener {
>    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
>       try {
>           AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.shutdown();
>       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
>       }
>    }
>    ...
> }
> ```
>
> Note that if container does not support annotations, you add the
> description to  web.xml:
>
> ```
> <listener>
>     <listener-class>user.package.YourThreadsListener</listener-class> 
> </listener>
> ```

**Resource Link:** https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/connector-j-relnotes-en/news-5-1-23.html

Comment: about the AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread, is it for mysql only ?

Comment: @MahmoudSaleh, yes it is.

Comment: Solution 1 for Oracle is a bad advice. The opposite is true

Answer (score 4):

My conclusions after running a few tests based on your code
and researching online:

- There's nothing to worry about ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28105803/tomcat8-memory-leak#answer-28106807)).
  Tomcat process is being finished and there's no memory leaks left behind.
- Even if you call something like `AbandonedConnectionCleanupThread.shutdown()`,
  you could still get that same Warning ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28105803/tomcat8-memory-leak))
- This warning happens when calling `startup.sh` and `shutdown.sh`.
  When running Tomcat from Eclipse, it doesn't show that Warning.
- Your shutdown method for the `Executor` is likely being called.
  For my tests, it was getting called even if I didn't define the `destroyMethod`
  for the executor.
- In this case, this warning is not related to any Spring Scheduling bean.
  `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool` returns a new `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`,
  which has the destroy method and it is getting destroyed, like I pointed out earlier. You can debug and see it for yourself.
- However, there's somewhere at your code calling `new java.util.Timer`,
  which calls `new TimerThread()`, 
  ass seen from your logging, and as pointed out by @Claudio Corsi.

**In order to debug it and if you are using Eclipse**,
you have to attache the source code for your JDK version.
Open the class declaration (hold ctrl and choose open declaration)
and click the "Attach Source Code" button. Make sure you have dowloaded the
exact same version. You don't even have to extract the zip.
If you're using Maven, just hold on a bit that it will download for itself.

Then, place a breakpoint in the constructor for `java.util.Timer`
and start debugging your application.

**Edit**: After identifying a reference to `java.util.Timer`, save it (as a bean, if it's not one) and call its `cancel` method on context destroy.

Answer (score 4):

I have also got the same issue with following error:

```
The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [cluster-ClusterId{value='5d29b78967e4ce07d9bb8705', description='null'}-localhost:27017] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
```

So, after a while I figured it out that I didn't do the maven install for all sub modules in my spring-boot application. So, double check if you are having same error that:

1. You have run `mvn clean install -U` for all sub modules in the project and for the project itself too.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to say root cause but thread name *[Timer-0]* gives a clue to find it. `java.util.Timer` class creates threads which has name pattern like *Timer-** as you can see in it's source code.

```
public Timer() {
    this("Timer-" + serialNumber());
}
```

Possibly the libraries that are in your classpath starts a *Timer* thread but doesn't cancel it or the code which is working in this thread stuck.

I may suggest put breakpoint in `java.util.Timer` and debug it to find which tasks is working on it. It may point the root cause.

Comment: you can also try a breakpoint in your contextDestroyed() and use e.g. jvisualvm to show thread dump of [Timer-0], maybe you get a clue from its stack about what part is responsible for starting it and fails to also have it stop

Answer (score 0):

Here we have identified this thread "Timer-0" being created by an old DB2 driver (db2jcc4 v4.19.66)

We upgraded to **db2jcc4 v4.32.28** (the latest version as of writing), and the issue was gone.

At a first look, this was coming from a thread monitoring a **DB2JccConfiguration.properties** file that we were not using.

So I assume that one of the possible causes of this problem comes from a thread leak caused by an outdated DB2 driver.

Tip: To find the offending library, we have set a breakpoint on the Timer.class instance, it was then obvious to determine that it came from our Db2 driver.